# Confusing python invalid syntax error

Tags: python

This is part of a stochastic simulation:

```
elif (D(dist(x, y, z)) > Dp): ### if passing to a region with lower diffusion constant
            rcross = np.sqrt(Dp/D(dist(x, y, z)))
            rd_nb = rd.uniform(0,1)
            if (Dp == 0.001): # in this case, the particle must be reflected
                s = para(x, y, z, R, dx, dy, dz)
                xc = x + s*dx
                yc = y + s*dy
                zc = z + s*dz

            x = 2*xc - xp
            y = 2*yc - yp           
            z = 2*zc - zp
            # position.append(x)
            t = t + delta_t
            #time.append(t)

        else: 
            if (rd_nb < rcross): # cross!
                s = para(x, y, z, rc, dx, dy, dz)
                xc = x + s*dx
                yc = y + s*dy
                zc = z + s*dz

                sqrt_delta_t1 = (xc - x)/(np.sqrt(2*D(dist(x, y, z))*xix)
                sqrt_delta_t2 = np.sqrt(delta_t) - sqrt_delta_t1
```

When I run the program, terminal displays the following message:

[image]

I am completely confused, how should that line be an error? I think all other parts are well coded. In addition, I cannot print anything (as a debugger) before that line either, which is weird. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The message says that there is an invalid syntax error at the last line: sqrt_delta_t2 = np.srqt(delta_t) - sqrt_delta_t1

Comment: It's not weird that you can't print anything before that line, your file had a syntax error, and so couldn't be compiled into byte code.

Comment: An image of textual data is considered poor form. In the future, please learn how to cut-and-paste from the Windows terminal.

Answer (score 5):

in  `(np.sqrt(2*D(dist(x, y, z))*xix)`

the parentheses do not match. 4 * `(`, but only 3 * `)`

Comment: Yes. And Python cannot see that until the assignment on the next line.

Comment: Yes indeed! Thank you so much!!